# Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I'm trying to make an image uploader, but it always give me this error

Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
here is my code controller code

```
public function postSubtitle()
{
    //$video = Video::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->find(Input::all('id'));

    var_dump(Input::all());
    $file= Input::file('name');
    echo $file->getClientOriginalExtension();   
}
```

and here is the upload form

```
{{ form_open({'url': 'video/subtitle', 'files': 'true'}) }}

                    {{ form_file('name', {class: 'form-control'} ) }}
                    {{ form_submit(trans('main.edit'), {class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'}) }}
                    {{form_close()}}
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `form`?

Comment: Show us your generated html form.

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="http://domain.com/video/subtitle" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="MAfYT5kmyzMfuVLKQ91F81v2Py9dl6L0RZ4kFJ9A">

                   <input class="form-control" name="name" type="file">
                     <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Edit">
                     </form>`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to handle file uploads, your `form` must have [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526273/397195). *(You might have that, but we don't know how your function `form_open` works.)*

If you have that but still get the same error it should mean that you haven't selected any file. If you don't upload a file, `Input::file('name')` will be `null` instead of an object.

So what you should do is to first check if it's not null, and then continue to handle your file.

```
$file = Input::file('name');
if ($file !== null) {
    echo $file->getClientOriginalExtension();  
}
```

Comment: var_dump returned NULL; Yes I have enctype.

Answer (score 2):

I thing should be remember. Pass only file path e.g name of input type only ,not pass any plain file name.this error occur when we pass wrong format, so i suggest you first check carefully,

Solution here :

```
$image = $request->file('edit_image');
  $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
  $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
  $image->move($destinationPath, $new_name);
  PlayersModel::where('id', $edit_user_id)->update($players_Obj);
```

Comment: Can you add some details